# Как автоматически данные с парсера перевести и переформулировать через гпт

Tags: python-3.x, chatgpt

Требуется реализовать скрипт для бота телеграм, который будет парсить свежие статьи.
Далее данные статьи перевести и переформулировать в chatgpt и готовый текст после всех итераций направлять в телеграм канал.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.